# Trello API: How to POST a Card from Google Apps Script (GAS)

Tags: google-apps-script

Google Apps Script has a `UrlFetchApp` method capable of creating a card in Trello.

How can it be used to create/modify cards in trello?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using the `sendHttpPost` example from the [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) for `UrlFetchApp` and the [docs for the Trello API](https://trello.com/docs/api/card/index.html#post-1-cards), I came up with this:

```
 // This sample sends POST payload data in the style of an HTML form, including
 // a file.

 function createTrelloCard() {

   //POST [/1/cards], Required permissions: write
   var payload = {"name":"apiUploadedCard", //(required) Valid Values: a string with a length from 1 to 16384
                  "desc":"description", //(optional)Valid Values: a string with a length from 0 to 16384
                  "pos":"top", //(optional) Default: bottom Valid Values: A position. top, bottom, or a positive number.
                  "due": "", //(required) Valid Values: A date, or null
                  "idList":"52017776e823fa1d51000819", //(required)Valid Values: id of the list that the card should be added to
                  //"labels": ,//(optional)
                  //"idMembers": ,//(optional)Valid Values: A comma-separated list of objectIds, 24-character hex strings
                  //"idCardSource": ,//(optional)Valid Values: The id of the card to copy into a new card.
                  //"keepFromSource": ,//(optional)Default: all Valid Values: Properties of the card to copy over from the source.
                 };

   // Because payload is a JavaScript object, it will be interpreted as
   // an HTML form. (We do not need to specify contentType; it will
   // automatically default to either 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
   // or 'multipart/form-data')
   var url = 'https://api.trello.com/1/cards?key=[YourAppKey]&token=[UserToken]' //optional... -&cards=open&lists=open'-
   var options = {"method" : "post",
                  "payload" : payload};

   UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
 }
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tested this. I've never written a Google App script or used the Trello API.

Comment: nice to see you come to the rescue. I Have to include an appkey and token, any Idea on how to include them?

Comment: @AperezC I updated it to what I think should work. Hard to tell to tell though; their docs leave a lot to be desired.

Comment: Thank you! It worked, i edited according to the modifications I did, but the credit is fully yours.